# code for Jpanel will not show yet the JPanel shows when the application is running in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel

so I am quite new to Java and I am struggling with my school project. Since I am new I tried to program my application in Netbeans and tried to do as much as possible dynamically. That is how I created the design of one of my Panels. I added there some labels, textFields, Jbuttons, and a textArea. I have to note that the JPanel is a class of itself. Then I closed NetBeans. When I launched it I could find the PanelClass but the design was gone and so the code - just a plain Panel was left. However, when I runned the application the Panel worked in the same manner as I programmed it the first time. When I closed the app I could not get to the Jpanel design or code. I do not understand what is happening.

I would show the screenshots, though I do not know how...

I tried adding some new components on the JPanel to see if they would show up once I runned the app, but they did not. The panel showed up only in the manner that I first programmed it.

I wish that I could access the JPanel with the components and the code that I added the first time I created the Panel.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Nice review, but is there something we can help you about?

Comment: There is no way of knowing what your problem might be unless you post the code you have used to create and display the JPanel.